# IntelliJ not recognizing imports from test directory (maven conventions)

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I've got a project with a maven structure (src/main, src/test) and somehow IntelliJ doesn't recognize imports from the test directory, although they're in the same package. When I run the Application it works. I already did "Invalidate Caches" and remove the intelliJ root folder (~/.IntelliJIdea2016).

[Folder Structure](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4575/5xcrimvh_png.htm)

[Test file](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4575/m64cz5g4_png.htm)

Any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: Delete the .idea folder in your project, then re-import your project.

Comment: don't link to things

Comment: There are possibly some bad imports for `some.old.pacakge.AbstractAccount` in `AbstractAccountTest` ... can you take a look at the imports in that file?